# postfix: aliases will be ignored

Tags: postfix, aliases

I have a server which is configured as a postfix MTA and on which runs also a munin node. In /etc/aliases I have add:

```
root:    hostmaster@my.domain
```

in the main.cf of postfix is configured:

```
mydomain = my.domain
myorigin = $mydomain
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
relay_domains = my.domain
append_at_myorigin = no
...
```

After each change of aliases or postfix configuration files I have called `newaliases` or `postmap <cfgfile>` and restart postfix.

Each time if munin will send a (error) email I get this in the maillog file:

```
Dec 22 16:45:19 myserver postfix/pickup[21509]: 5CFBA2011E0: uid=995  rom=<munin>
Dec 22 16:45:19 myserver postfix/cleanup[22094]: 5CFBA2011E0: 
    message-id=<20151222154519.5CFBA2011E0@my.domain>
Dec 22 16:45:19 myserver postfix/qmgr[21510]: 5CFBA2011E0: from=<munin>, size=999, nrcpt=1 
    (queue active)
Dec 22 16:45:20 myserver postfix/smtp[22099]: 5CFBA2011E0: to=<root@my.domain>, 
    orig_to=<root>, relay=internal.my.domain[XXX.182.189.136]:25, delay=4.2, 
    delays=3/0.01/1.1/0.09, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host 
    internal.my.domain[XXX.182.189.136] said: 550 5.1.1 <root@my.domain>: Recipient address 
    rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Dec 22 16:45:20 myserver postfix/cleanup[22094]: A98B72012D2: 
    message-id=<20151222154520.A98B72012D2@my.domain>
Dec 22 16:45:20 myserver postfix/bounce[22100]: 5CFBA2011E0: sender non-delivery 
    notification: A98B72012D2
```

Don't understand why "root" (orig_to) was not replaced with "hostmaster@my.domain" like it was specified in the aliases file. Seems postfix append the `myorigin` value to "root". Not sure why because I have also specified `append_at_myorigin = no`.

Whats going on here? I want to replace the "root" address with "hostmaster@my.domain". How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure about what "my.domain" is exactly, but [*aliases*](http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html) are only used for local deliveries.

Instead, you probably want to use the [virtual maps](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html).

As root (or sudo)

In /etc/postfix/virtual (or where *virtual* is)

```
root    hostmaster@my.domain
```

In main.cf

```
virtual_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

or (modern versions of postfix)

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

after the virtual map has been modified

```
# postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
# postfix reload
```

Beware that all mail for "root" will be redirected to "hostmaster@my.domain".

Comment: Sure you mean `virtual_maps`? Or should it `virtual_alias_maps`?

Comment: On my old postfix, main.cf has `virtual_maps` but the new manual indeed says `virtual_alias_maps`

Comment: `virtual_maps` works for me. At my first try I have forgotten the "s" (`virtual_map` instead of `virtual_maps`). Thanks al lot.

Answer (score 20):

In my case I want to use `/etc/aliases` (because some packages uses it so you have to verify changes and replicate to `/etc/postfix/virtual`

The problem why it doesn't work is in `myorigin`. If you set `myorigin`, all mails sent to root, nobody and other locals are changed automagicaly into `root@myorigin`

in my case:
/etc/aliases:

```
nobody:   root
root: admin@example.com
```

/etc/mailname:

```
myhost.example.com
```

/etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
myorigin = /etc/mailname
myhostname = othername.example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = othername, localhost.localdomain, localhost
```

In this case all mails sent to nobody are changed into `nobody@myhost.example.com` (because of `myorigin`) and then sent out somewhere.

I have to change `mydestination`:

```
mydestination = myhost.example.com, othername, localhost.localdomain, localhost
```

and now mail sent to `nobody` is redirected to `root`, which changes into `nobody@myhost.example.com`, but because it is in `mydestination` it looks into aliases and changed into `root@myhost.example.com`, but because it is in `mydestination` it looks into aliases, and redirected into `admin@example.com`, which isn't in mydestination and it is sent where it should be sent ;D

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one.  Another example where local delivery works is shown here: https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/03/taking-e-mail-back-part-2-arming-your-server-with-postfix-dovecot/2/

Comment: This is in fact a *way* better answer in the sense that it is getting to a solution that is using the de-facto standard /etc/aliases instead of diverging to the postfix-only /etc/postfix/virtual file.

Comment: setting correct value into `/etc/mailname` is what fixed a problem for me. I had `domain.local`, but had to change to `hostname.domain.local`